# Can drivers create a problem while switching from 32 bit to 64 bits?

Tags: drivers, 64-bit

I may sound like a noob , but I am going forward with it anyway.I have a windows xp 32 bit os .But my processor(Core 2 Duo) supports 64 bits .I want to install ubuntu.Now my question is whether I should go for ubuntu 32 bit version or the 64 bit version.I already know their pros and cons. But I have heard that drivers or graphics may create a problem if I am switching from 32 bits to 64 bit os.Is that true?I don't want to know the difference between the 32 bit and 64 bit os, but the technical glitches that may arise post installation.

Answer (score 0):

If your processor supports 64-bit then you can install ubuntu 64 bit version along with windows.Its not matter,if you already installed a 32bit or 64 bit windows os.It was better to try ubuntu-64 bit live disk before installing it on your hard-disk.

Comment: What graphics card & how much RAM? I ran 32 bit XP on one drive and 32 bit Ubuntu on my dual core system from 2006 until I converted to 64 bit Ubuntu with 9.10. Best if decent video card and 4GB of RAM which works fine for me with all the current versions.